# Crossword grid verification

Tags: code-golf, crossword

Validate a proposed crossword grid.

Entries should be full programs that simply test a proposed grid
to determine if it meets a set of conditions for making crossword
solvers happy.

### Input

The input will be the name of a file representing the crossword
grid. The input filename may be passed as an argument, on the
standard input, or by other conventional means other than
hardcoding.

**Grid file format:** The first line consists of two white-space
separated integer constants M and N. Following that line are M
lines each consisting of N characters (plus a new line) selected
from `[#A-Z ]`. These characters are interpreted such that `'#'`
indicates a blocked square, `' '` a open square in the puzzle
with no known contents and any letter an open square whose
containing that letter.

### Output

The program should produce no output on valid grids and exit with
normal termination state. If the proposed grid fails, the program
should produce a diagnostic error message and exit with a
abnormal termination state (i.e. not 0 on unix) if this is
supported by your execution environment. The error message should
indicate both which condition for validity is violated and the
location of the offending square; you are free to chose the means
of conveying these facts.

### Conditions for validity

Valid grids will have no answers (across or down) that are only 1
character long (extra credit for making the minimum length a
input parameter), and will exhibit the usual symmetry. The usual
symmetry means the crossword remains the same after (three
equivalent descriptions of the same operation):

- reflection through it's own center
- reflection both vertically and horizontally
- 180 degree rotation

### Test input and expected output

Passes:

```
5   5
#  ##
#    
  #  
    #
##  #
```

Fails on short answer:

```
5   5
## ##
#    
  #  
    #
## ##
```

Fails on symmetry:

```
5   5
#  ##
#    
  #  
#   #
##  #
```

### Aside

This is the second of several crossword related challenges. I
plan to use a consistent set of file-formats throughout and to
build up a respectable suite of crossword related utilities in
the process. For instance a subsequent puzzle will call for
printing a ASCII version of the crossword based on the input and
output of this puzzle.

Previous challenges in this series:

- [Crossword numbering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/318/crossword-numbering)

Comment: Does the symetry requirement also apply to the grid's known contents, or only to the structure (# or not #)?

Comment: Only to the structure of blocked and in-play squares.

Comment: Oh, this one already had a bounty. Bummer. Still, I think two answers are a bit few.

Comment: Center symmetry and 180°-rotation are the same thing - aren't they? But I don't see vertical, nor horizontal symmetry. But 90°-rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby - <s>215</s> 207

```
t,*d=$<.map &:chop;n,d,e=t.size+1,(d*S=?#).gsub(/[^#]/,W=" "),->c,i{puts [c,i/n+1,i%n+1]*" ";exit 1}
0.upto(d.size-1){|i|d[i]==d[-i-1]||e[?R,i];d[i]==W&&(d[i-1]!=W&&d[i+1]!=W||d[i-n]!=W&&d[i+n]!=W)&&e[?L,i]}
```

Ungolfed:

```
h, *g = $<.map &:chop
w = h.size+1
g = (g*?#).gsub(/[^#]/," ")
error = ->c,i{ puts [c,i/w+1,i% w+1]*" "; exit 1 }
0.upto(size-1) { |i|
        error[?R, i] if g[i] != g[-i-1]
        error[?L,i] if g[i]==" " && (g[i-1]!=" " && g[i+1]!=" " || g[i-w]!=" " && g[i+w] != " ")
}
```

.

```
h, *g = $<.map &:chop
```

This basically removes the last char (line break) of each input line by calling the `chop` method on them, and returning an array of the results.

`h` takes the first element of this array and `*g` takes the rest. So we end up with the first line in `h` and the crossword grid lines in `g`.

```
g = (g*?#).gsub(/[^#]/," ")
```

`g*?#` joins (`*`) the array `g` with the `"#"` (`?#` is a character literal). This is the same as `g.*("#")`, or `g.join("#")`. Then every non `#` is replaced by a space.

For the symmetry check we just have to check if the char at every index is equals to the char at the opposite index in the string:

```
0.upto(g.size-1) { |i| if g[i] != g[g.size - i - 1]; error() }
```

In Ruby we can index strings from the end using negative indexes (starting from `-1` instead of `0`), so that `g[-i-1]` is the opposite of `g[i]` in the string. This saves a few chars:

```
0.upto(g.size-1) { |i| if g[i] != g[-i-1]; error() }
```

We can save a `;` by using a conditional statement:

```
0.upto(g.size-1) { |i| error() if g[i] != g[-i-1] }
```

In the golfed version we can save a few more chars:

```
0.upto(g.size-1){|i|g[i]==g[-i-1]||error()}
```

In a previous version I used recursion for iterating over the string:

```
(f=->i{g[i]&&f[i+1]&&g[i]!=g[-i-1]&&error()})[0]
```

An out of bound access to `g` returns nil, so once `g[i]` returns `nil`, this stops the iteration.

Output format:

```
{ L | R } line-number column-number
```

L for length errors, and R for rotation error (so `L 1 2` means length error at line 1, column 2)

Comment: Would you care to explain a little for those of us who don't speak ruby? I can see how you've removed any non-blacks from in-play squares, and how the answer length checking works (nice, BTW), but I'm not quite getting the symmetry check.

Comment: I see a problem here of how the width of the grid is determined - by taking the length of the 1st line. That is incorrect, it will only work on the example where that line is "5---5" (three spaces in the middle). If it was "5 5" it wont work!

Comment: Also i think there is a problem with "veritcal wrap-around", when going over the 1st row and looking one row down (+n) and one row up (-n) - the latter will look in the last row and may mistakenly pick-up space from there!

Comment: Well you are right for the width of the grid; I assumed that on the first line, the second number is always aligned to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

### Reference implementation

**c99**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readgrid(FILE *f, int m, int n, char grid[m][n]){
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int c = 0;
  while ( (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
      if (j != n) fprintf(stderr,"Short input line (%d)\n",i);
      i++;
      j=0;
    } else {
      grid[i][j++] = c;
    }
  }
}

int isSymmetric(int m, int n, char g[m][n]){
  for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
      if ( (g[i][j]=='#') != (g[m-i-1][n-j-1]=='#') )
    return j*m+i;
  return -1;
}

int isLongEnough(int m, int n, char g[m][n], int min){
  /* Check the rows */
  for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    int lo=-(min+1); /* last open square */
    int lb=-1;       /* last blocked square */
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      if ( g[i][j] == '#' ) {
    /* blocked square */
    if ( (lo == j-1) && (j-lb <= min+1) ) return lo*m+i;
    lb=j;
      } else {
    /* In-play square */
    lo=j;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Check the columns */
  for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
    int lo=-(min+1); /* last open square */
    int lb=-1;       /* last blocked square */
    for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
      if ( g[i][j] == '#' ) {
    /* blocked square */
    if ( (lo == i-1) && (i-lb <= min+1) ) return lo*m+i;
    lb=i;
      } else {
    /* In-play square */
    lo=i;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Passed */
  return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  const char *infname;
  FILE *inf=NULL;
  FILE *outf=stdout;
  int min=1;

  /* deal with the command line */
  switch (argc) {
  case 3: /* two or more arguments. Take the second to be the minium
         answer length */
    if ( (min=atoi(argv[2]))<1 ) {
      fprintf(stderr,"%s: Minimum length '%s' too short. Exiting.",
          argv[0],argv[2]);
      return 2;
    }
    /* FALLTHROUGH */
  case 2: /* exactly one argument */
    infname = argv[1];
    if (!(inf = fopen(infname,"r"))) {
      fprintf(stderr,"%s: Couldn't open file '%s'. Exiting.",
          argv[0],argv[1]);
      return 1;
    };
    break;
  default:
    printf("%s: Verify crossword grid.\n\t%s <grid file> [<minimum length>]\n",
       argv[0],argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  /* Read the grid size from the first line */
  int m=0,n=0,e=-1;
  char lbuf[81];
  fgets(lbuf,81,inf);
  sscanf(lbuf,"%d %d",&m,&n);

  /* Intialize the grid */
  char grid[m][n];
  for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      grid[i][j]='#';
    }
  }

  readgrid(inf,m,n,grid);

  if ((e=isSymmetric(m,n,grid))>=0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Symmetry violation at %d,%d.\n",e/m+1,e%m+1);
    return 4;
  } else if ((e=isLongEnough(m,n,grid,min))>=0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Short answer at %d,%d.\n",e/m+1,e%m+1);
    return 8;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 278 chars

```
char*f,g[999],*r=g;i,j,h,w;main(e){
for(fscanf(f=fopen(gets(g),"r"),"%*d%d%*[\n]",&w);fgets(g+h*w,99,f);++h);
for(;j++<h;)for(i=0;i++<w;++r)if(e=*r==35^g[g+w*h-r-1]==35?83:
*r==35||i>1&r[-1]!=35|i<w&r[1]!=35&&j>1&r[-w]!=35|j<h&r[w]!=35?0:76)
exit(printf("%d%c%d\n",j,e,i));exit(0);}
```

As you might expect, the error messages have themselves been golfed. They take the following form:

`11L8` - indicates a length error at row 11 column 8

`4S10` - indicates a symmetry error at row 4 column 10

Answer (score 1):

### APL (115)

```
{∨/,k←⍵≠⌽⊖⍵:'⍉',(,k×⍳⍴k)~⊂2/0⋄×⍴d←(,⊃,/(g(⍉g←⍳⍴⍵))×{k↑1⌽1⊖0 1 0⍷¯1⌽¯1⊖⍵↑⍨2+k←⍴⍵}¨⍵(⍉⍵))~⊂2/0:'∘',d}d↑↑{'#'≠⍞}¨⍳⊃d←⎕
```

If the grid is not symmetrical, it outputs `⍉` followed by the coordinates, i.e. for the example it gives

```
⍉ 2 5  4 1
```

If the grid has short answers, it outputs `∘` followed by the coordinates, i.e. for the example it gives

```
∘ 1 2  5 2
```

Explanation:

- `d↑↑{'#'≠⍞}¨⍳⊃d←⎕`: read the first line as a list of numbers and store in `d`, then read as many lines as the first number, and reshape as a matrix of size `d`. 'Closed' squares are stored as 0 and 'open' squares as 1.
- `∨/,k←⍵≠⌽⊖⍵`: store in `k` the places where the grid is asymmetrical. If there is such a place...
- `'⍉',(,k×⍳⍴k)~⊂2/0`: output a ⍉ followed by the offending coordinates
- `⋄`: otherwise...
- `~⊂2/0`: remove the zero coordinates from the following list:
- `¨⍵(⍉⍵)`: for both the grid and its transpose...
- `¯1⌽¯1⊖⍵↑⍨2+k←⍴⍵`: surround the grid with  zeros (i.e. closed squares)
- `0 1 0⍷`: see where it contains an 'open' square enclosed by two 'closed' squares (= too short)
- `k↑1⌽1⊖`: remove the ring of extra zeros again
- `,⊃,/(g(⍉g←⍳⍴⍵))×`: multiply by coordinates and transposed coordinates, and join together, to form a list of offending coordinates (and a lot of zeros which we remove).
- `×⍴d←`: store the offending coordinates in `d`, and if there are any...
- `:'∘',d`: output a ∘ followed by the coordinates.