# Is it a Valid Crossword Grid?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid, crossword

In crossword terminology, the *grid* is the region into which the crossword answers are inserted, consisting of white and black squares. The crossword answers, called *entries*, are inserted into contiguous sequences of white squares in a row or column, separated by black squares.

[image: Example of a crossword grid]

For straight (American) crosswords, the grids usually follow a specific set of rules:

- They should have 180 degree rotational symmetry (if there is a black square in the \$x\$th row and \$y\$th column, there should be a black square in the \$x\$th-to-last row and \$y\$th-to-last column).
- All entries must be at least 3 squares long.
- All white squares must be joined in a single region.
- No row/column can be completely filled with black squares.
- Every white cell/square must be the intersection of both a horizontal and a vertical entry.

Some examples of invalid and valid crossword grids:

[image: Valid and invalid crossword grids]

**Your challenge:** given a grid consisting of two unique values representing black and white squares, determine if it's a valid crossword grid. Assume that it's a square grid with \$n\$ rows and columns (so there are \$n^2\$ white/black cells), where \$n \geq 3\$. (You can take input in any reasonable format -- e.g. a 2D array.) For example, if \$n=3\$ there is only one valid grid (I'm using `.` for white cells and `#` for black cells):

```
...
...
...
```

If \$n=4\$, there are 3 valid grids:

```
....  #...  ...#
....  ....  ....
....  ....  ....
....  ...#  #...
```

If \$n=5\$, there are 12 valid grids:

```
.....  #....  ##...  #....  ##...  ##...  
.....  .....  .....  #....  #....  ##...  
.....  .....  .....  .....  .....  .....  
.....  .....  .....  ....#  ....#  ...##  
.....  ....#  ...##  ....#  ...##  ...##  

....#  ...##  ....#  ...##  ...##  #...#  
.....  .....  ....#  ....#  ...##  .....  
.....  .....  .....  .....  .....  .....  
.....  .....  #....  #....  ##...  .....  
#....  ##...  #....  ##...  ##...  #...#
```

Examples:

| Input | Output | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.........` | True | Valid grid |
| `#..............#` | True | Valid grid |
| `...#........#...` | True | Valid grid |
| `.........................` | True | Valid grid |
| `##...#.............#...##` | True | Valid grid |
| `.................................................` | True | Valid grid |
| `........................#........................` | True | Valid grid |
| `....###.....##......##.....##......##.....###....` | True | Valid grid |
| `................................................................` | True | Valid grid |
| `##....####....##...........##......##...........##....####....##` | True | Valid grid |
| `...##.......#...........##.....##.....##...........#.......##...` | True | Valid grid |
| `#...............` | False | No 180 degree symmetry |
| `#...#......#...#` | False | 2-letter entries |
| `#..##..##..##..#` | False | 2-letter entries, filled-in columns |
| `#........................` | False | No 180 degree symmetry |
| `.......#...###...#.......` | False | 1-letter and 1-letter entries |
| `######....#....#....#....` | False | No 180 degree symmetry, filled-in column & row |
| `######...##...##...######` | False | Filled-in columns & rows |
| `...#......#......#......#......#......#......#...` | False | White squares not contiguous, filled-in column |
| `.................###....#....###.................` | False | 1-letter entries |
| `...#......#...............##.....................` | False | No 180-degree symmetry |
| `....#.......#.......#........######........#.......#.......#....` | False | White squares not contiguous |
| `..#.........#.......#......##......#.......#.......#.........#..` | False | 1-letter and 2-letter entries |
| `.#......#..............................................#......#.` | False | 1-letter entries, white squares not contiguous |
| `...........................##......#............................` | False | No 180-degree symmetry |
| `####............................................................` | False | No 180-degree symmetry |
| `#......##......##......##......##......##......##......##......#` | False | Filled-in columns |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Shortest code wins.

Comment: Note: this is different from the [previous crossword grid decision challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/883/crossword-grid-verification).

Comment: Can we take input as a square array?

Comment: `#...#......#...#` is invalid as it has length two entries. (Also a couple of test cases are repeated.)

Comment: Why is `....#....` invalid? I had checked it with these 4 rules, and seems it passed all of them.

Comment: @tsh one letter entries

Comment: @thejonymyster Okay, I thought that a single white cell is not considered as an entry.

Comment: @Neil Sorry for the late response -- I intended to allow taking the input as a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Just a suggestion on phrasing: Like @tsh I would not consider "length-one entries" to be possible, so they wouldn't be able to disqualify a grid.  I would capture your intent by saying "Every white cell/square must be the intersection of both a horizontal and a vertical entry".

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>40 35</s> 33 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-5 thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)!

```
;ZµŒg§’:2;§Ȧ
ŒṪḢạ§ỊẸʋƇ@ƬiƊȧÇȧU⁼ṚƊ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of `1`s (white) and `0`s (black) that yields `1` if valid or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9866tDWo5PSDy1/1DDTysj60PITy7iOTnq4c9XDHYse7lp4aPnD3V0Pd@041X2s3eHYmsxjXSeWH24/sTz0UeOehztnHev6/3D3Fv@HO5oOrTnc/v@/srIeECgrcyEYehDABeaiM8CKuDB0AQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##pVK9bsIwEN7vNb4uLBk6lqUPgMTUhb2qWrF1YqMdiBQ2tnYrQy1VjEUKf4sjoqhvYV7EQFOcc7BNpJ7ku5zvvrvPl3u67/cHWrd7cr6dPEixG77dXLelKD5pO1GLL5VO1fJDCrVK1DL9GefxbT57zJNCZHEh7nYva7V4zxOtVt9y/tzJRnJz1VXpq5xlcUtrRJaAjsp4h@O8KIUinxDAYQYL@DHeWr4AggigjP@ZyOci/JKmJMs6wMlynnZL7lT5xBMc6Bp9K@33knBGqYyYQ7g0YpiJoHqX4WirKsLVUdjGNDTn47d6Ak7GcK8BEFiK@uRYP9bGmUa8VS0DCABPX@RjfEEMKrSlaFKbAOB/a@5e6caWYP847AE).

#### How?

```
;ZµŒg§’:2;§Ȧ - Link 1 (check entry lengths & presence): list of lists of 1/0, Grid
;Z           - concatenate the columns
  µ          - start a new monadic chain - f(rows + columns)
   Œg        - group runs of equal elements of each row/column
     §       - sums of each run
      ’      - decrement (i.e... all black: -1, 1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5: 4, ...)
       :2    - integer divide by two        -1    0    0    1,   1,    2, ...
          §  - {rows + columns} sums
         ;   - concatenate
           Ȧ - any and all? -> 0 if either: an entry of length 1 or 2 exists, or
                                            any row or column has no entry
                               else 1

ŒṪḢạ§ỊẸʋƇ@ƬiƊȧÇȧU⁼ṚƊ - Main Link: list of lists of 1/0, Grid
ŒṪ                   - multidimensional truthy indices -> "WhiteCoordinates)
            Ɗ        - last three links as a monad - f(WhiteCoordinates):
  Ḣ                  -   head (first coordinate -> initial "Current")
          Ƭ          -   collect up while distinct, applying:
         @           -     with swapped arguments - i.e. f(WhiteCoordinates, Current):
        Ƈ            -       filter keep those (of WhiteCoordinates) for which:
       ʋ             -         last four links as a dyad - i.e. f(WhiteCoordinates, Current):
   ạ                 -           absolute difference (vectorises)
    §                -           sum each
     Ị               -           insignificant? (effectively "in (0,1)?")
      Ẹ              -           any? - i.e. any are neighbours/same?
           i         -   index of {WhiteCoordinates} in that (or 0)
                        -> 1 if white cells are fully connected else 0
              Ç      - call link 1
             ȧ       - logical AND
                   Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(Grid):
                U    - {Grid} reverse each
                  Ṛ  - {Grid} reverse
                 ⁼   - equal? -> 1 if 180-degree symmetry else 0
               ȧ     - logical AND
```

---

Also at 33 as a lone Link (although it performs redundant checks):

```
,ZµŒg§’:2;U⁼ṚƊ;ŒṪḢạ§ỊẸʋƇ@ƬiƊ$;§)Ȧ
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! Like the two further bytes saved too. I’ve written [an R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266031/42248) inspired by this one, partly just as an exercise in taking something optimised in a golfing language that has plenty of built-ins and implementing it in a general purpose language that has fewer.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 562 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
def g(b,B):
 q=[(x,y)for x,y in B if b[x][y]=='.']
 Q=[q.pop(0)];S=[Q[0]]
 for x,y in Q:
  for X,Y in[(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)]:
   u=(x+X,y+Y)
   if u in B and u not in S and'.'==b[x+X][y+Y]:Q+=[u];S+=[u]
 return not{*q}-{*S}
F=lambda x,l,c=0,k=0:k if not x else F(x[1:],l,(T:=c+(x[0]==l))*(x[0]==l),max(k,T))
def f(n,b):
 B=[(x,y)for x,r in E(b)for y,_ in E(r)]
 D=[(x,y)for x,y in B if'#'==b[x][y]]
 return all((n-x-1,n-y-1)in D for x,y in D)and g(b,B)and all(F(i,'.')>2and F(i,'#')<n for i in b)and all(F(i,'.')>2and F(i,'#')<n for i in zip(*b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZbb9owFH5efoVXS4sNDiKdJlV03kPV8jgJgbZWWdQmYGjU4FAnWWFtfzs7ThRIINxUS2Af51y@8/n4Mlskj5H8ejFTy@UNFzKdCuUlwhiJMZoQn13RjoGeuUPmbEHHkULQo0CiKxSMke/MXWfhcm62TNdAPe48t2bRjLSpe9nnTs9puzBdsuqBs0y@ZXcgO8RmbcqIlXdtZtlZZ1NXK6KUk3nzli2ad1SLEDHNY3tyBEMZJVrsaxEQcA54mreAqHnndnpN7qQAI@sMpESSKqlNXhvP79Zro/9udHnoTf2RB@hCNuRt9sTbnScdRnueIxHGAnXJ3LE7LmiQQYcPmyC2IeOQ0sZqyKbenDyxAaUZb2Mima95u6rwpjTYG@Jn4oLd56KigO66nmAT50lpktc5eGFIiLTmwJq0FkAZaF@XWb6mmp989fRIG3RJwIAj@uNcz2QSNul3mdkF2so/QfdfMCMNn9KlTjeJ7v3IUyMSQ86fJA9kQkIhQWw0Wt/oZUE9c2In6ARN6a78KE9OBCx4rs4kcGEMbvoDxNHZ2Znx0Craw9tApeLtlxcGkJkKRsYDblUarlHR06vv9V6OU9kLAq@tAUTXg6qpt99sdf5wGdDaL96H69h2gg98og@McwtckLFDxCfi@EBqeSyMi76cXRVWWVjr7ygWXMNQNduq17LK4SpuFQX0M0L2RRuNxEQJgeLFdCoStcj0cflX6J9boUgSoZCQiQpEzNA4CEMxsmCXDaMwncp4O9jRUSulWC7RwtAuwusTw97AotdixWv1b3/g7STQF6Sil5LD8p9uhcPuZva5ZVze8Ud2hcvfj0EC2J5TT4k4uyKGkUyCSRqlNXTX1HSFAox3rsI2f1u4tkp574JatQu6Wcm4hLMEr1btGE50FNza4QbjPd6LUW11nW@zgw8cWnvPOLyTd4ZeDqS32/cxkA4tEsYYf@xQPOC//jQ8ut@51wx9eRvG6pqHvQG0kp@RFAzp@70Vz8IgIeYfaVL9aPCYD@8hjoLiw5tJYTaOhUrgOdVYPTE8eItZtksp4hyJv14IzynDmCn95jATEScxmmmz0WeTLv8D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>186</s> 183 bytes

```
\.
-
s`^(?!(.)+.?(?<-1>\1)+$(?(1)^)).+

ms`.*^#+$.*|.*(?<!-)--?(?!-).*

O$`.
$.%`
ms`.*^#+$.*|.*(?<!-)--?(?!-).*

1`-
@
+m`^((.)*)(@|-)(.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)$))?(?!\3)[@-]
$1@$4@
^[¶#@]+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY0xDsIwDEV336KKkeJEsZTCiJrcgAO0jcLAwAADZey5eoBeLDhQxIgH/6fvb/3H5Xm9n0sZGBxMOenQaCbLQYej893gyaIO2lMiYgtwmzKbpCyymdlIqHHknKRF2QCcMDMg7/LfpM8OItibdEqjIR1nR5rNutTqthNPiltCovo07KmPbgT0EQ8RUr8uKo4WS2FmpWQBV/pCHXj7YsKm6nfash@o9AI) Takes input as a square array and outputs `1` for valid, `0` for invalid. Explanation:

```
\.
-
```

Change `.`s to `-`s are they're easier to match.

```
s`^(?!(.)+.?(?<-1>\1)+$(?(1)^)).+
```

Delete everything if it isn't rotationally symmetric.

```
ms`.*^#+$.*|.*(?<!-)--?(?!-).*
```

Delete everything if there is a row of `#`s or if there are one or two `-`s on their own.

```
O$`.
$.%`
```

Transpose the array.

```
ms`.*^#+$.*|.*(?<!-)--?(?!-).*
```

Check the transpose for a row of `#`s or one or two `-`s on their own.

```
1`-
@
```

Change one `-` to a `@`.

```
+m`^((.)*)(@|-)(.*¶(?<-2>.)*(?(2)$))?(?!\3)[@-]
$1@$4@
```

Flood fill `-`s with `@`s. Note that I use `(?(2)$)` although I used `(?(1)^)` above because this is a multiline match and so the final character could be at the beginning of a line.

```
^[¶#@]+$
```

Check that all of the `-`s were filled.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES11), 176 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Expects a binary matrix, with `1` for white cells and `0` for black cells. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=(m,i)=>m<(h=z=>m=m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>z?/^(0*222+)+0*$/.test(r.join``)?m[x][m.length-1-y]:z:v&[-1,0,1,2].some(d=>m[y+d%2]?.[x+~-d%2]==i)?i=2:v)))()?f(m,i):h``+""==h(h``)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVTLjpswFFWlrrzqJ1h42tiBeBKkSlWmHlZTqduO1A1DBUrMo-KRAsnkofRHZpPFzL6_0_maGggJEEhnroTvw_f43Htt8fAYRlO-2z3NU3vw6e8fm-FA8Qi7Dj5jl62FZgENrBnGsbIS4bhwFspSOGvt8gce9lVVlYk87F9c0pQnKY7pz8gLTZNogb409ID6PHRSdzAarIzxerz4oA9GylAZKapBkyjgeCpo9JU8fa8aGtWX8u9BZjLmEc1j6nhBCMFEs_PKxq5pypLEmIuFRYq6n9-8m0RhEvmc-pGDJf275XtTQyJXIOa_5l7MsWQnEqExt6ZfPJ_frsIJHhKaRrdp7IUOJjSZ-V6KpbtQpNlRfGNNXJxAdg03AELPzmwGJYnADaxx3YX613BR8sGYp_M4vIJbgfJ5Cu8hg8l-ArDfh0P6UYFBHgysVHB8487NcoZNurnY3G-3pgJ7To-QfM45v04pTYzcn2S-nCkGe1RkiQZhrRwxpCy43Q9m9_z2gZYCEKJtghBobCCQLQcvw7YF2qWgqZ-ICppOTOdZXRvtnZQItO-0bLjLRWc5XlxkcQ5Cpa7WWaesOsd8UE1oQTfKr6XlQdC8QAoqd5CbWQBVvxPIEVuhQLXLBAgdqq4vx53qkknl5bxQnV5IjbPlFZ9yVKDdPTZHfnzghzY700CVqpGB0BlgaYGuiv8jB9S5d9usoFUAapvlKwQ0-32tLn5S_wA)

#### How?

The same helper function `h` is used to process two passes:

1. We flood-fill the matrix, replacing `1`'s with `2`'s. We start at the first empty cell located on a border. If it doesn't exist, the grid is invalid anyway and will be identified as such during the next pass.
2. We rotate the matrix 3 times by 90°. We convert each resulting row to a string and make sure that it matches the following regular expression:

   ```
   /^(0*222+)+0*$/
   ```

   i.e. the entire string is made of groups of three or more `2`'s (with at least one such group) and optional groups of `0`'s.

   Finally, we make sure that the 3rd rotation leads to the same matrix as the 1st one to validate the 180° rotational symmetry.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                        // f is a recursive function taking:
  m,                         //   m[] = input binary matrix
  i                          //   i = flag used during flood-filling,
) =>                         //       initially undefined
m < (                        // compare m[] with its updated version
  h = z =>                   // h is a helper function ...
  m =                        // ... which updates m[]
  m.map((r, y) =>            // for each row r[] at index y in m[]:
    r.map((v, x) =>          //   for each value v at index x in r[]:
      z ?                    //     if z is truthy:
        /^(0*222+)+0*$/      //       if r[], once converted to a string,
        .test(r.join``) ?    //       matches this regular expression:
          m[x]               //         apply a 90° rotation
          [m.length - 1 - y] //
        :                    //       else:
          z                  //         force the final test to fail (*)
      :                      //     else:
        v &                  //       if v = 1
        [-1, 0, 1, 2]        //       and there's some direction d
        .some(d =>           //       such that:
          m[y + d % 2]       //         the neighbor cell
          ?.[x + ~-d % 2]    //         in that direction
          == i               //         is equal to i
        ) ?                  //       then:
          i = 2              //         set i and the cell to 2
        :                    //       else:
          v                  //         leave this cell unchanged
    )                        //   end of inner map()
  )                          // end of outer map()
)() ?                        // if m[] was modified after flood-filling:
  f(m, i)                    //   try to flood-fill some more
:                            // else:
  h`` + "" == h(h``)         //   do the 1st and 3rd rotation match?
```

<sub>(*) For the 1st and 2nd rotations, `z` is set to `['']`, which is coerced to an empty string. For the 3rd rotation, it is set to the result of the 2nd rotation.</sub>

Comment: For a moment there you were ahead of Retina 0.8.2 but fortunately I found that I'd copied some insufficiently golfed code from my answer to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154363/ so I was able to save three bytes from both answers. (My answer to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188874/ was correctly golfed which is what tipped me off.)

Comment: @Neil You encouraged me to golf this some more. ;-) But I'm just one byte ahead, so that may not last for long...

Comment: (Ok, 6 bytes ahead now.)

Comment: You can save 1 byte if you don't mind to swap the 0 / 1 in the input, so you can change `!v` to `v`: `f=(m,i)=>m<(h=z=>m=m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>z?/^(0*222+)+0*$/.test(r.join``)?m[x][m.length-1-y]:z:v&[-1,0,1,2].some(d=>m[y+d%2]?.[x+~-d%2]==i)?i=2:v)))()?f(m,i):h``+""==h(h``)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 67 bytes

```
Ｆθ⊞υＳ¿⁼υＥ⮌υ⮌ι¿⬤⁺υＥθ⭆θ§λκ∧№ι.⬤⪪ι#÷⊖Ｌλ²«Ｅυ⭆ι⎇⁼λ.ψλＪ⌕θ.⁰¤.¿‹ＬＫＡＬΣυ⎚«⎚¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDLbsIwEEXX8VdYZDOW0qjtlhXiIaWiUlT4gSgZwGLiJI6Niiq@PfVAUuqFfX3ndezyVNiyKWgYDo2V0CmZ@/4EPpGZab3bOavNEZSaC32QsO58QT1HP4sWvvCCtkfwKpGT1iosybkLIsjJ/2V3iXx0Gy8Ll5kKv4ESeeai4JgKlo03DnQiZ@mMrdBk15J@WDFbmXErfdEVwgpLizUahxVs0RzdCYj7vKs7xI@I8jDPAQ/0/6eHXnu0prDX6UU0Dbwmkrh6LqIPX7f7BjY6YHVT/JUjGx2w@B40P3WLfT8R5IhnpmaQ0dr5OvwRIy0JCwtchtQjE0ZPa6R9Y30Tt2FI0zSOwyZSVpPgJe5@MMV4xs/QmPsQrIaXC/0C) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a square array of strings and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for valid, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ⊞υＳ
```

Input the square array.

```
¿⁼υＥ⮌υ⮌ι
```

Check that it's rotationally symmetric.

```
¿⬤⁺υＥθ⭆θ§λκ∧№ι.⬤⪪ι#÷⊖Ｌλ²«
```

Concatenate the array with its transpose and check that each row contains a `.` but when split on `#`s does not contain runs of exactly `1` or `2` `.`s.

```
Ｅυ⭆ι⎇⁼λ.ψλ
```

Write just the `#`s from the array to the canvas.

```
Ｊ⌕θ.⁰
```

Jump to a position where there should be a `.`.

```
¤.
```

Fill the canvas with `.`s starting from here.

```
¿‹ＬＫＡＬΣυ⎚
```

If this didn't fill all of the original `.`s then just clear the canvas.

```
«⎚¹
```

If all of the `.`s were connected then clear the canvas and output `-`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 245 bytes

```javascript
s=>new Set([...s].map(p=(c,i,a)=>c^1||[n=s.length**.5|0,(m=(s,t,v=a[t])=>v&&''+v!=s?(b=v=>v[0].at?b(v[0]):v)(s)[0]=v:s)(m(a[p=~i+~n]=[p],p-~n),p+1),+a.at(~i),a[i+~n]|a[i-~n]&a[i-~n*2],a[i-1]|a[i+1]&a[i+2]]).flat(1/0)).size<4*!s[-p]*/^1/m.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZfb9s2EH@OPsUVBCLSlim7Wx/mVAk6YAX2MGRAC@xBU1dapmwGMiWQtNMsbr56epIsW0rtBN0ISCTvz@@OdzySN2IjbGpU6Ua6mMvHLHq00aWWt/BBOhpzzm3CV6KkZUTTQAWCRZfpp8l2G@vI8lzqhVsOBvzNdhzQVURt4IJNJGKXoNzm/Nz3h5tXkb2is2iDhHiccOGuZrQasemGUctwFG2mltEVFXEZPajhg06iuEyCcvSgWVAOJywYCtSjD4oFIq4FttgjOzlv@sHrpOKMJjVjOKnpw9dJwniWo@YkHDPGrfpXvv158MrGozIZhJ8m4Yo7aR168RiGUBb5XabyHDJTrGDpXGmnYbhQbrme8bRYhS796ZewNEVZWJGPjERktZEjpefyi9KL0Uq6ZTEnLY6XFto6EA4iyNY6darQQDWDe@8MzX0sftdOLqShDMTMOiNSB0XpnWmU/0O4JXcGtSqF7RbGF7XSuzwvbkHLRW0aWtONy24pQeq5d6YytANvYcxAwzBChmqT1cBcX/8KIk2ltaAsLNbCCPRFzsEVYKRbGw1rhM6Ull24yhENlz1A9p3CzgR6Y26VlUEtXdm5WWM4dGFWIocqjNK4u50b3tkOpZKNdXLhfb3wrmc3MnW8gf1zp0DfGSPuOOq7wt2VCO8L5wdwDxuRr@UU4x3ArVFOzHKcYQxRROr1SpqGkom8cgqTk6nF2hzE4Cu78HZJK4WxEvOAOxqqfLSrhcEA@BsG0SVUxVH7ghlqaoT@E4CqeZbbXKWSKhiADgD7IUxYNWHcyDIXyAt5uAjgSyWOvygCn/twBROYQrVZbwqlqf@39g9OVXs1FVZadOizx9sGH9F5jxB@rBGyYz8hN9RqtCftoU5Sj7eO/b4V0rHPf7Q9r0ZeViO7iLSBOTUlL1v7MZ8bRELavpeNft@ZHOQPSSBHVttfRh@oK3I07RzeV7vf6@SqHh7IpPt1pI@vt@H30t3dBq0@2S@u/3vK7/6qdsAnvRW@1PX96sau48CRgjll77v8nY7D05SRju2OyaNiexjCT8gR8ox6O2phyAul8mxlkZNBPLKbn62JQ47/V2n1tiL5r/0O5jPerWpF8UlQ5so1x2x9hJv6ZK9Pf2paLvjVK4UFYDher/YvfBFQvyovnyXM8/bHMs8K85tIl5TGCu@cpL4K7j2o7hpb5JLnxYJmFF8xIPFUx@vm8Rs)

Input a multi line string, 1 for white cells, 0 for black cells, line break (`\n`) separate each rows. Output true or false.

---

## JavaScript, 263 bytes

```javascript
a=>new Set(a.map((r,y)=>[r.map(e=(c,x)=>!c||[(m=(s,t,v=a[t])=>v&&''+v!=s?(b=v=>v[0][1]?v:b(v[0]))(s)[0]=v:s)(m(a[p=x+[,y]]=[p],[x-1,y]),[x,y-1]),e=a.at(~y).at(~x),a[y-1]?.[x]||a[y+1]?.[x]&&a[y+2]?.[x],r[x-1]||r[x+1]&&r[x+2]]),e,a.some(r=>r[y])]).flat(1/0)).size<3
```

```js
f=

a=>new Set(a.map((r,y)=>[r.map(e=(c,x)=>!c||[(m=(s,t,v=a[t])=>v&&''+v!=s?(b=v=>v[0][1]?v:b(v[0]))(s)[0]=v:s)(m(a[p=x+[,y]]=[p],[x-1,y]),[x,y-1]),e=a.at(~y).at(~x),a[y-1]?.[x]||a[y+1]?.[x]&&a[y+2]?.[x],r[x-1]||r[x+1]&&r[x+2]]),e,a.some(r=>r[y])]).flat(1/0)).size<3

const parse = (s, n = s.length ** .5) => [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => [...s.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n)].map(v => v === '.'));
const testcases = `
......... True
##.....................## True
#..............# True
...#........#... True
...#........#... True
......................... True
##...#.............#...## True
................................................. True
........................#........................ True
....###.....##......##.....##......##.....###.... True
................................................................ True
##....####....##...........##......##...........##....####....## True
...##.......#...........##.....##.....##...........#.......##... True
#............... False
#...#......#...# False
#..##..##..##..# False
#........................ False
.......#...###...#....... False
######....#....#....#.... False
######...##...##...###### False
...#......#......#......#......#......#......#... False
.................###....#....###................. False
...#......#...............##..................... False
....#.......#.......#........######........#.......#.......#.... False
..#.........#.......#......##......#.......#.......#.........#.. False
.#......#..............................................#......#. False
...........................##......#............................ False
####............................................................ False
#......##......##......##......##......##......##......##......# False
`.trim().split('\n').map(r => [parse(r.split(' ')[0]), r.endsWith('True')])

testcases.forEach(([i, e]) => {
  console.log(f(i), e);
});
```

Input boolean matrix, output true or false.

```javascript
a=>new Set(
  a.map((r,y)=>[
    r.map(e=(c,x)=>!c||[ // for each cell, which is either empty or
      // generate an unique symbol for its connected area
      (m=(s,t,v=a[t])=>v&&''+v!=s?(b=v=>v[0][1]?v:b(v[0]))(s)[0]=v:s)(m(a[p=x+[,y]]=[p],[x-1,y]),[x,y-1]),
      // its 180 rotated position is non-empty
      e=a.at(~y).at(~x),
      // its ^ cell is non-empty or its v and vv cells are non-empty
      a[y-1]?.[x]||a[y+1]?.[x]&&a[y+2]?.[x],
      // its < cell is non-empty or its > and >> cells are non-empty
      r[x-1]||r[x+1]&&r[x+2]
    ]),
    // at least one non-empty cell this row
    e,
    // at least one non-empty cell this column
    a.some(r=>r[y])
  ]).flat(1/0)
).size<3 // if every non-empty cell connected, they have same symbol (count as 1)
         // if all other condition holds, they will be all true (count as 1)
```

Transpose the matrix also costs 263 bytes, maybe someone can golf one of them a bit

```javascript
m=>new Set([m,m.map((r,y)=>r.map((_,x)=>m[x][y]))].map(a=>a.map((r,y)=>[r.map(e=(c,x)=>!c||[a==m||(m=(s,t,v=a[t])=>v&&''+v!=s?(b=v=>v[0][1]?v:b(v[0]))(s)[0]=v:s)(m(a[p=x+[,y]]=[p],[x-1,y]),[x,y-1]),e=a.at(~y).at(~x),r[x-1]||r[x+1]&&r[x+2]]),e])).flat(1/0)).size<3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>196</s> <s>185</s> <s>184</s> <s>177</s> 176 bytes

```r
\(x,`~`=t,`+`=sum,a=apply,e=~which(x,T),i=~~e[,1],`?`=any){while(+i<+(i=e[,a(e,2,\(y)?colSums((i-y)^2)<2)]))1
+i-+e?x-rev(x)?a(rbind(x,~x),1,\(y,z=rle(y))?!(z$v*z$l-1)%/%2&+y)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVRBTuswEN2w8ilCBpCHOEXpikWtHAJ2bb8SwAVLaShJCkkRuQibfgn2XOf_S3AF3AYSJ60LjBSP7XnP82Zi-flvsnyZWAP3dZ5N3NN_byOas6AMeMYCJ-DpfMpCHs5mUcEELx9u5OWNApwjk7wsxZB5Yxb4AQ_jAh9VNBLUkQOHSq5iIRWsz0a0QP_yNjqbT1NKpVvgnz4O-jhG9IgjXUf4uZuIe5qjH9LkQsZXKkOZI_NWXLbgiTq1QPT36eLg_nhxELkeHp4c9o-cAp8q3f_33kWuqrCitVaaZkk6i2TWTGzotQzIaqhX6tu6URnpmYwA6LSaC2DmGM8yBcAUWDMAqvin65mWsDPHj0VW5wB8eV1nO6W-aPBEB2xhd-S3YOtN0m3HagP0bwPRQLUDofXrCECtsT00EX1YmXZjfug229_KCZvCN3NoVHON3QY3F7su0wgjeqoOAmAH8WtGTIq_sZq165Z2FWw1Att6-Qsj3Xp_64l2udZTm1n2aBTbOBx647Fa2Mgs9driNMwSmdPc4tyyewoWJ7cPFrfSuySjkYivM_XkojKSVo-byNkEq3dvuaz8Bw)

A function taking a square matrix of logical values and returning a single logical value. This was inspired by and works more or less the same as [@JonathanAllan’s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266007/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

Thanks to [@pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55372/pajonk) for saving 9 bytes!

Comment: [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NCsIwFIT3nkKhynvmBWlXLppT6M4fGjXSQKzSP5uquYgbBb2DV_E2RnQ18M0wM9d7fntsuzF_VuWWj9-vOTSUuESUlLBEFNWOpJCHg7GkhDumep36wBRJC-fUjMIFnjw1CpiOGWjhmQRFEc3BoswsrPdmUu0KAM0tLiOMI8QFYtj5mkxzps4Nz1UNDZ57VWZ0UYKEfKWzjV9yDVL47aJW5H7FIkIb1MM2MDzE_qgfDZhnePn9v_3lrx8) by flipping TRUE<->FALSE in output.

Comment: Thanks! I’d tried using `-` but kept ending up with no saving.

Comment: [Another -7](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NDsFAGIb3TkGi8n3mm0i7suikh2DnJzMYMUlbUlqdYi5iQ8IBHMdtjLB6F8_7d70Xt8e6HfNneVjz4fs1hZqkk-JAkkmxLzNSQu12qSUt3HFjlhtvGCMZ4ZyeUDgjmUihcosnT1MNzMQMjPBMgaaIpmAxWW7TUZntAQy3OI8wjnCGGLYSZjjT55oXuoIazwqKhclXfsLVSOE3TI0ofK1FTDrQdKt-0015iMEgiHrM4uV3_PaXv34A) by getting rid of `unlist` and reassigning `any`.

Comment: [Another -1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7LDgExFIb3noIEOUdPIzMri2n6EOxc0qITTcaYDMN0RF_EhoS91_E2Kqz-xfffrvfy9kjbCX9Wh5SP3q8Z1KS8EgdSTIl9tSUtdFFkjozwp41dbYJhgmSF92ZK0ZyUVELnDs-BZgaYTRhYEZgGQzHNwKFc7bJxtd0DWO5wEWMS4xwxajHLmZE1L80RapQayqXN12HB10jRN0uNKEOrQ5QdaLrHQdPNeIS9YS_uM4eX3-_bX_76AQ) - sorry, I missed that one earlier

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <sup>95 93</sup> 92 bytes

```
(2<*#])@((#;._2"1@,.&0,&,0=1&#.)@,|:)*/@,(-:|."1@|.),&,[:(]+.+./ .*)^:_~1=[:|@-/~$j./@#:I.@,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVTBSsNAED15yVdsO5rNpskk6UHs2sCiUBDFg3hrYxGxLUUQtD0IoT_ipR78qPoBfoeRbZLdNEnTgd3J7rx9M7Mzm8-v-XpzfXuBxLI9YXX7NkRMWHCO4y6z_X7HY-1AOGj6wui1eBCdtniPUqONdEJCTihxiE94Mlwkl3c3g-_lYuKebUYZleTakjim44eBCciEE3OWuHQsl8eYmGNkiXXIraiDHfQI2uyBj1dBOOSxcL3V8Rw9AfwKhSN9_Bz9MmMWInHFCRdAohGhSM3QmCZ7Q04mO4bnp9krofdvy8XsgxpyOU1sqdBsC1AToCo4M4J2ptZSdIBVosQAKmNGC9CAZT97FQKqDPpRAAncKqxaQjOvh8cvmQFSraagB6EucrxetxRZQlPITIOBrPO2sQaPL-9qXxWvUmsvUEdl45UdVmIArUfUy8kS1acSiDr9S1lDN1Q1ddbCgd0sa7wqHA1upljJ_Elmd1IJU5lyXwUoQA1D-qUwVSSzR7JTjd5OMaZS0Wt_WDiVTAX_h-qcSedU8gEqf_frtdR_)

*-2 thanks to Neil's idea of catting transpose with input instead of using over*

Takes input as a 0-1 matrix, where 1 means empty space.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 61 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
˜ƶIgôΔ2Fø0δ.ø}2Fø€ü3}*εεÅsyøÅs«à]˜0KÙgIDø«εÅγsÏ3@DgĀª}˜`IÂíQP
```

Input as as matrix of `1`s for white squares and `0`s for black squares.
Outputs a 05AB1E-truthy/falsey result, so `1` as truthy, and `0` or a positive integer as falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9Jxj2zzTD285N8XI7fAOg3Nb9A7vqAUxHzWtObzHuFbr3NZzWw@3Flce3gEkD60@vCD29BwD78Mz0z1dDu84tBokeW5z8eF@YweX9CMNh1bVnp6T4Hm46fDawID//6OjDXVA0AAIwaxYHaiIIRYRQ7gIXD1EJVgEiQ8WwdSFYi6KCMyuWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##pVM9SwNBEO3zK8K@QpBzCaYTJAqHjYUJgo0EjHocAYkh2QgpAhKwtrERUthq9BqTcKDVrtgE7kf4R86c9@Gu7t1FHLid25l5b2Z3Zs@7jeOm5V@QasdirL/W7jRbzDotNlvtHtsoEqNv2kxMTP5iFMj2Ces1zhJf5WP4uL9Ca/x@s0D2eiyyEn8@ep9xxxYT72Z9R7glb0KFOwh@FwjxWh5wZ9WbelNx1e0Ld7Hysbirz0elXXFrc8cULh8HXu@5K67LW6b9dskfBvPREXfEUDzVqj6hBwafVfxDQmMhBgFVBAtToJJ9GEXTJGCADEhQQBYugy/NhRwMEEZEiqZtkZPnD6WGXECs5WrVtPLmOz66bGhOqFavssghv1sYmyD1IjRB/jRATReQXBnkYydHUBfZJy@BKIO1pNJ1SckMpNQO/cwAmRP084KlnFIqbdgXBWhKDJABjf8CCuTMeubTQM5YYxn2qIf/fRn6V7C0ljtC6p8).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Verify rule "*All white squares must be joined in a single region.*":

```python
˜             # Flatten the (implicit) input-matrix to a single list
 ƶ            # Multiply each value by its 1-based index (so all 1s become unique)
  Igô         # Convert this list back into a matrix equal of the input-dimensions 
Δ             #  Loop until it no longer changes to flood-fill:
 2Fø0δ.ø}     #   Add a border of 0s around the matrix:
 2F     }     #    Loop 2 times:
   ø          #     Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     δ        #     Map over each row:
    0 .ø      #      Add a leading/trailing 0
 2Fø€ü3}      #   Convert it into overlapping 3x3 blocks: 
 2F    }      #    Loop 2 times again:
   ø          #     Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    €         #     Map over each inner list:
     ü3       #      Convert it to a list of overlapping triplets
 *            #   Multiply each 3x3 block by the value in the (implicit) input-matrix
              #   (so the 0s remain 0s)
 εεÅsyøÅs«à   #   Get the largest value from the horizontal/vertical cross of each 3x3
              #   block:
 εε           #    Nested map over each 3x3 block:
   Ås         #      Pop and push its middle row
     y        #      Push the 3x3 block again
      ø       #      Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       Ås     #      Pop and push its middle rows as well (the middle column)
         «    #      Merge the middle row and column together to a single list
          à   #      Pop and push its maximum
]             #  Close the nested maps, flood-fill loop, and outer loop
 ˜            # Flatten the resulting flood-filled matrix
  0K          # Remove all 0s (the black squares)
    Ù         # Uniquify the values of each island
     g        # Pop and push its length (which is 1 if it was a single island of 1s)
```

[Try just step 1 online for all test cases.](https://tio.run/##pVNBS8MwFL7vV4T3DoLUMPUmyBCGIF4UwYvsUF2shdGNJRN62EXwH3gRdvAqk522MdBTA14G/RH@kdratSaathMfJC/J@973XvJeuty@dFl0Cyd9JoS/1eu7nmBt4nq9gdgjYPlNR8hpM3i1anBwJQZ2J7c1Pu5ezjboafC8X4MjTsQN6zNiE@56TocRl3dsr02612SbN2I0RMvR@zyYOHIaPuwcykU9nFK5GCbLmEm@7Q6DyWY4C2fynvtyEc/BWD61lqP6sXx0IqDnLviMgxyD14WhFcwb0QXQTMACpJpgfJSofJ@iaJEkDKg65F6IZX4lfEUmrPBBTBErRYu2WBHnD6mmXIiZVrPVw6qbb/zqsdFwQz17nUWF/C5hdoRKLdIjVIfB0VAFzJ8M1WvnV9An1aZOiWiNtaYyVUmLjFiQO5p7BrG0g34@sBJTCWWEfVEgLcAglrhmq4QCK3q99GtgRVvjOuyrGv73Z5h/wdparQi0PgE)

Step 2: Verify rules "*All entries must be at least 3 squares long.*" and "*No row/column can be completely filled with black squares.*":

```python
I             # Push the input-matrix again
 D            # Duplicate it
  ø           # Zip/transpose the copy; swapping its rows/columns
   «          # Merge the two matrices together
    ε         # Map over each inner list:
     Åγ       #  Run-length encode it; pushing a list of values and lengths
       s      #  Swap so the values are at the top
        Ï     #  Only keep the lengths for the truthy (==1) values
         3@   #  Check for each whether it's >= 3
         D    #  Duplicate this list
          g   #  Pop and push its length
           Ā  #  Check whether it's truthy (>= 0)
            ª #  Append this check to the list
    }˜        # After the map: Flatten the list of lists
      `       # Pop and dump all values to the stack
...
P             # Take the product of all values on the stack
```

[Try just step 2 online for all test cases.](https://tio.run/##pVPNSsNAEL77FMPOwUuMh94EqULOUhG8iGAa13Zxu6nJxpJDQQTPvoAvoPXmD4K3xJvQh/BFYmKauKv5qTiQnezMfN/M7sy6vt1nNDknPY9KGa6NPSYkPQYmxoHcAGKE1kDGj1b0aqyQbUcGNi993Y/L@71Vcze63Ux9HgWbc6BCeoz6YEvg1PYldMA/C2wvNXFXDGB7xwLmgxzSFCBc8NzJuuPyYCTAcUdjTiXlIZwwztMqJkwOoc9t57Qg6aZpSWLFL9Fs/hRfzR/8@LqzZQ3eLqK76fvNUS8h5j4jIfVJPCPCJVMjeu4mB8QshBgETU0wNWWq3OdRZp1kDKgCShRiE66Br86FLRjEPGKhzLottuT5Q6k5F2Kh1Wr1tOrmO35x2VhxQr16nUUN@d3CwoRKL3ITql8FsKILWF4Zqscuj6Avqk9dMtEGa0lV1SUtM2JN7Vg9M4iNE/TzgpWcSqrKsC8KNGtiEBugxV9GgS2z3vg0sGWscRn2RQ//@zKqX8HSWu0IOfwE)

Step 3: Verify rule "*They should have 180 degree rotational symmetry.*":

```python
I             # Push the input-matrix yet again
 Â            # Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse
  í           # Also reverse each inner row
   Q          # Check if the two matrices are still the same
```

[Try just step 3 online for all test cases.](https://tio.run/##pVO9TsMwEN55ipNvYAlmYENCVaXOiAqJBTG4wbQWrl0ShyoDS98GARtiYWvehBcJCfnBBicp4qT44rv7vjv7zjpmM8Hze3IWcWPSg1UklOHXINQqMcdAgnQyN9nrZPse7JFxaBImW9/oY/N8vk@n28eTwhdxYFICVyYSPAZmQHIWGziC@C5hUWGSWs1hfDoBEYNZ8AKgNER6fRhqmSwVhHq5ktxwmcKNkLKoYi3MAmaShbcNyahIS/Jsk71Mc0IvBEl5TLInojR5CLZvo/yS0EZIQJA6goWpVO2@iqJdUjKgDWhRiH24Hr4uFw5gEKuIWtGuLQ7k@UOpFRdio@1q3bT25ju@vmz0nNCt3mWxQ363sDGh1YvKhPbnAXq6gO2VoX3s9gjuYvvspRRnsHZUvi45mRE7akf/zCD2TtDPC7ZyWqm8YV8USDtiEHugzV9JgQOz3vs0cGCscRf2uof/fRn@V7CztjtCrj4B)

Step 4: Combine all checks and output the result:

```python
P             # Pop all values on the stack and push its product
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```