# Tips for golfing in Postscript?

Tags: code-golf, tips

As one of the less popular languages, it's difficult to find literature on the avant garde of postscript hackery. So what discoveries have the golfers here made to exploit the stack model (or other features) to overcome Postscript's inherent verbosity?

Comment: Found some external pages: https://sites.google.com/site/codegolfingtips/Postscript

Answer (score 4):

While most postscript operators are syntactically identifiers (and therefore must be space- (or otherwise-) delimited), the names `[`, `]`, `<<`, and `>>` are self-delimiting and scanner will detect them without intervening space. For the same reason, you cannot refer to these names with the usual `/literal` syntax (eg. `/[` is two tokens: an empty literal name equivalent to `()cvn cvlit`, and the executable name `[` equivalent to `([)cvn cvx exec`).

In order to redefine these names, which cannot be mentioned by name, we can use strings which are implicitly converted to names when used as keys in a dictionary (convenient!).

This example illustrates abusing these operators to perform arithmetic.

```
%!
([)0 def
(])1 def
(<<){add}def
(>>){mul}def
 ]]<<]]]<<<<>> =
%1 1 add 1 1 1 add add mul = %prints 6
```

Also `<<` and `[` (and `mark`) all mean the same thing.

---

My own postscript interpreter, [xpost](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/), also makes the right-curly brace available with some restrictions. [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/hV5Ie0jR45c/discussion)

Comment: Also, `/` ends the previous token so you don't need a space before it.

Answer (score 4):

### Embedded Decoder

A Postscript program has a unique(?) ability to read it's own program text as data. This is normally used by the `image` operator which receives a *data-acquisition-procedure* as input, and this procedure often uses `currentfile` followed by `readline`, `readstring`, or `readhexstring`. But seen another way, `image` is just another looping operator, so any loop can *read-ahead*. An example is the line-printer emulator from the Green Book.

Using the `token` operator invokes the scanner on a file or string, pulling off a number or space- (or otherwise-: see other answer) -delimited name.

A simple PS interpreter in PS:

```
{currentfile token not {exit} if dup type /arraytype ne {exec} if }loop
```

---

### Binary Operator String Decoder

Since I can't seem to get *raw* binary tokens to work for me (see other answer), I've made use of the "embedded decoding" idea to exploit the binary token mechanism to pack code into 8-bit strings, and then manipulate and parse the commands from the string *on the fly*.

```
/.{
    <920>  % two-byte binary-encoded name template with 0x92 prefix
    dup 1 4 3 roll put  % insert number into string
    cvx exec  % and execute it
}def
/${
    //.   %the /. procedure body defined above
    73 .  %"forall" (by code number)
}def
```

The `.` procedure takes a number from the stack and inserts it as the second byte in a two-byte string, the first byte being the prefix-byte for a binary token, specifying an executable system name. We save a byte in the hexstring by using a rule of the scanner that an odd number of nibbles in the hexstring is padded with an extra 0 nibble, so 3 hex nibbles produces a 2-byte string. The string is then marked *executable* and called with `exec` which invokes the scanner, produces the desired executable system name, and then loads the name and executes the operator. The `$` does this on each byte of a string on the stack, using the `.` procedure *twice*, once as the loop body, and then to execute the looping operator `forall` by number.

More compactly, these procedures look like this:

```
 /.{<920>dup 1 4 3 roll put cvx exec}def/${//. 73 .}def
%123457890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
%        1         2         3         4         5
```

So, 55 chars buys binary token strings. Or, for 6 (maybe 7, if you terminate it with a space) chars, you can load the [G library](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G) with `(G)run` which defines `.` and `$` as above (+ a few others to extend the range of ascii-reachable codes).

Further illustrated in my [crossword puzzle answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3877/2381).

Comment: Actually, if the postscript is in encoded form, then this requires you be extra careful about comparing stuff.  Specifically, if you are looking at operators, you _must_ parse it as a token and then compare the token's _name_ to the target value.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quickie: wrap multiple definitions in `[...>>begin` to eliminate the keyword `def` (nb. `[` is the same as `<<`).

```
 def def
[>>begin
```

So remember: **more than <del>three</del> two ... *flock together*!** ;)

Comment: Shouldn't the rule be "more than two"? Compare `/a 1 def/b 2 def/c 3 def` with `<</a 1/b 2/c 3>>begin`. We need more spaces for def.

Comment: Wow. I hadn't though of that. Yes, the calculation needs improvement.

Comment: Actually, this should be `[/a 1/b 2/c 3>>begin`

Comment: face-palm. . . .

Comment: I've got some new ideas described in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything there. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess it scrolled away. I've got a start on a [golfing library](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/3gaExFSE4ZE/discussion) and a suite for [APL-like calculations](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/zv6uWG14PYA/discussion).

Comment: This might not apply if you are naming something that terminates on a self-delimiting token. In `/a{pop 2 mul}def` or `\b[2 3]def`, the `def` only costs 3 characters, not 4.

Answer (score 4):

### Replace hexstrings with ASCII85

Probably old news, but I just learned it. :)

You can do it using the postscript interpreter interactively with an encoding filter and cut-and-paste. But I'm going to show how to use `dc` to do it "by hand".

So, here's a hex string. We split it into 4-byte chunks.

```
95 20 6e d8   d0 59 49 35   50 74 ba c5   08 2d
```

Firing up dc, we input these as 32-bit (unsigned) big-endian-byte-order numbers. Then *mod*-off base-85 digits (there should be 5 until you get to 0).

```
0> dc
16i
95206ED8
Ai
d85%n85/
82
d85%n85/
83
d85%n85/
82
d85%n85/
78
d85%n85/
47
d85%n85/
0
```

Padding the last chunk with `00 00`, yields (decimal), omitting the same number of bytes that we padded.

```
47 78 82 83 82   66 81 72 79 83   25 72 82 25 69  2 53 30 [2 53]
```

Add 33 to shift into the printable range of ASCII and poof! ASCII85.

> 80 111 115 116 115 99 114 105 112 116 58 105 115 58 102 35 86 63
>  which decodes to:
>   Postscript:is:f#V?
>
>   %%%Oops! should say 'fun'! I screwed up somewhere. :)

Wrap it in `<~` ... `~>`, and Level-2 Postscript can access 8-bit data, cheaper than hex.

Comment: Please could you explain how to use the interpreter to ASCII85 encode data? I don't yet understand how to use filters and that would really help.

Comment: You can use `/f (%stdout)(w)file /ASCII85Encode filter def` and then write data into the "file" (ie. *filtered file*) `f`.

Comment: Thanks! And, so I don't forget, you can then use it like this: ```f (testing 123) writestring f closefile```

Answer (score 4):

When generating graphical output and console output does not matter, use `=` instead of `pop`.

Answer (score 2):

## Factor-out repeated uses of long operator names

If you're already using a `<<>>begin` dictionary, there is a constant overhead of `/?{}` 4 characters per redefinition. So an operator of length *n* repeated *N* times will yield a character-count change of
(4 + *n*) - (*N* * (*n* - 1)).

Setting this formula equal to 0 gives the equation of the *break-even* point. From this we can solve for each variable in terms of the other, yielding
*n* = - (*N* - 4) / (1 - *N*) and
*N* = (4 + *n*) / (*n* - 1) .

No we can answer questions like, "For how many uses of 'print' is it worthwhile to abbreviate?" *n* = 5, so *N* = 9/4. Take the ceiling, since you can't effectively call print 1/4 times. So, 3. 3 uses. And indeed,

```
print print print
/P{print}p p p
```

(assuming you've already paid the overhead of `<<>>begin` to activate the definition, of course).

Of course, binary tokens makes this kind of moot, giving you the first 255 names from the system name table as 2-bytes: 0x92, 0x??. And binary tokens are also self-delimiting, requiring no whitespace before or after, since the high-bit of the first byte is outside of the ascii range.

Answer (score 2):

## Binary Tokens

For the ultimate *zip-up* of a PostScript program that final frontier is *binary tokens* which allows you to remove long operator names completely, at the cost of no longer having an ASCII-clean program.

So starting with a compacted block of postscript code

```
[/T[70{R 0 rlineto}48{}49{}43{A rotate}45{A neg rotate}91{currentdict
end[/.[currentpoint matrix currentmatrix]cvx>>begin begin}93{. setmatrix
moveto currentdict end end begin}>>/S{dup B eq{T begin exch{load exec}forall
end}{exch{load exch 1 add S}forall}ifelse 1 sub }>>begin moveto 0 S stroke
```

We look up all the names in the back of the [PLRM](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/PLRM.pdf) (Appendix F, pp. 795-797)

```
appearance
in
vim    dec  meaning

<92>   146  'executable system name' binary token prefix
^A     1    add
^M     13   begin
^^     30   currentdict
'      39   currentmatrix
(      40   currentpoint
2      50   cvx
8      56   dup
9      57   end
=      61   eq  !)
>      62   exch
?      63   exec
I      73   forall
U      85   ifelse
d      100  load
h      104  matrix
k      107  moveto
n      110  neg
<85>   133  rlineto
<88>   136  rotate
§      167 stroke
©      169 sub
```

And then type them in prefixed by a `146` (decimal) byte. [vim help for entering arbitrary bytes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters#By_character_value)

Then in vim, the condensed file can be typed directly, so:

> [/T[70{R 0<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>133}48{}49{}43{A<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>136}
>   45{A<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>110<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>136}
>   91{<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>30<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>57
>   [/.[<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>40<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>104
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>39]<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>50>>
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>13<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>13}93{.
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>156
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>107<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>30
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>57<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>57
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>13}>>/S{<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>56
>   B<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>61{T<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>13
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>62{<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>100
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>63}<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>73
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>57}{<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>62{
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>100<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>62

... you have to enter a space here to terminate the `^V`-62 and start the 1, but you can back up and delete it later ...

> 1<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>1S}<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>73}
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>85

... have to enter a space here to terminate the `^V`-85 and start the 1, but you can back up and delete it later ...

> 1<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>169}>><kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>13
>   <kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>107

... 3rd digit of 3-digit code terminates the byte-entry so the following `0` here is normal, conveniently ...

> 0 S<kbd>^V</kbd>146<kbd>^V</kbd>167

Which will look like this on screen (in vim):

```
[/T[70{R 0<92><85>}48{}49{}43{A<92><88>}45{A<92>n<92><88>}
91{<92>^^<92>9[/.[<92>(<92>h<92>']<92>2>>
<92>^M<92>^M}93{.<92><9c><92>k<92>^^<92>9<92>9<92>^M}
>>/S{<92>8B<92>={T<92>^M<92>>{<92>d<92>?}<92>I<92>9}{<92>>
{<92>d<92>>1<92>^AS}<92>I}<92>U1<92>©}>><92>^M
<92>k0 S<92>§
```

This one can often be omitted entirely if the aim is just to show a picture. Ghostscript paints most things to the screen without needing `showpage`.

```
¡    161   showpage
```

[*This actually isn't working. Ghostscript's giving me `undefined` and `syntaxerror` for these tokens. Maybe there's some **mode** I need to enable.*]

Comment: Maybe it's something about *this* program. The [online compactor](http://postscript-prettifier.appspot.com/) doesn't like it, either.

Comment: I suspect UTF-8 encoding is what killed you here. vim really wants to use UTF-8 for the file which means you get (more or less) 0xc2 (194) before top-bit-set characters. I've just tried your instruction after typing vim filename, on screen it looks like you say it should but the file has 194s in it. If you're on Linux, try using od -t u1 -c to check the file contents. Even vim -b/:set binary wasn't enough, I had to do LANG=C vim -b or vim -b then :set encoding=latin1. Personally, I've been using Emacs hexl-mode.

Answer (score 2):

## Change negative rolls to positive

Negative rolls can [always be changed to positive rolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997536/how-do-you-keep-the-roll-operator-straight/).

```
3 -1 roll
3 2 roll

5 -2 roll
5 3 roll
```

Comment: Which is more efficient `3 -1 roll` or `3 2 roll`? In my mental model, the former should be more efficient because it just takes one move. Is my mental model correct?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. Here's [my implementation](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/bin/xpost_op_stack.c#151), where all negative rolls are converted to positive as the first step. I think it would still require at least 2 moves (move 3rd value *up*, move 3 values *down*) with a flat-array implementation of the stack. But my stack is segmented so access goes through function calls to manage the segments; so there are certainly more efficient ways to implement than I have done. ... One thing I see now: I should check for stackunderflow *outside* of the loops.

Comment: The source file has moved since my last comment. [Here's my implementation](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_op_stack.c#151) of the `roll` operator.

Answer (score 1):

### Use my G library

https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G

It's a text file. No extension, for the shortest possible syntax to load it.

It permits this [203-char Sierpinksi Triangle program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6604/2381)

```
[48(0-1+0+1-0)49(11)43(+)45(-)/s{dup
0 eq{exch{[48{1 0 rlineto}49 1 index
43{240 rotate}45{120 rotate}>>exch
get exec}forall}{exch{load
exch 1 sub s}forall}ifelse 1 add}>>begin
9 9 moveto(0-1-1)9 s fill
```

to be rewritten in 151 bytes as

```
3(G)run $
{A - B + A + B - A}
{B B}

{A - B - B}7{[ex{du w{(>K?\2u)$}if}fora]}rep
cvx[/A{3 0 rl}/B 1 in/-{120 rot}/+{-120 rot}>>b
100 200(k?B9)$ showp
```

[workfile with comments](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G/blob/master/siertriG.ps)

Using the abbreviated system names feature, `1(G)run` completely removes the burden of long operator names. An operator name need only be long enough to distinguish it from the others.

So

- `add` becomes `ad`
- `mul` becomes `mu`
- `index` becomes `i`
- *etc, etc.*

Use the [PLRM](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/PLRM.pdf) Appendix F for the standard table of operator names.

And the feature of Operator Strings is available even if the abbreviated names is not selected. The bare library has a "base-level" selected by adding simply `(G)run` with no further decorations.

The base level includes a new function `.` which accepts the integer code for an operator (the same Appendix F mentioned above) and executes it.

The new function `$` iterates through a string and calls `.` upon each one. So the ascii code directly selects the operator by number.

A new function `@` lets you reach down to the bottom of the table in Appendix F by treating the space character (Ascii 0x20) as 0.

A new function `#` lets you reach further up into the table by first adding 95 (0x5F) so the space char 0x20 is treated as 127 (0x7F), the very next code after the last printable ascii character `~` 126 (0x7E).

Two new functions `!` lets you access a deeply nested structure of arrays and/or dicts with an *index array* of indices/keys, rather than tedious expressions of many `get` (and `put`) operators.

`(G)run` 7 chars buys the base-level.

`1(G)run` 8 chars buys that AND abbreviated system names.

`3(G)run $` 9 chars immediately begins an *implicit-procedure block* scanning sources lines until the next blank line, and defining the first line as a procedure called `A`, the next line is defined as a procedure called `B`, etc. This should remove most of the `def`s needed for defining lots of stuff, without needing to wrap them in a dictionary, nor even explicitly giving them names.

Answer (score 1):

## Error handling with `stopped`

For example, suppose `f` takes an argument from the stack and you want to apply `f` until the stack is empty.

`{f}loop`

will give a stack underflow when the stack becomes empty. So you could use

`{count 0 gt{f}if}loop`

but a shorter solution is:

`{{f}loop}stopped`

(Note that this leaves `true` on the stack.)

Answer (score 0):

## Hex colors in a string

`(AZm){255 div}forall setrgbcolor` selects the HTML color `#415a6b`, because `A` is hex `41`, etc, so  `(AZm)` is the same as `<415a6b>`.

So if you have a bunch of different colors to use, you can put them on the stack ready to apply `setrgbcolor` for only 3 extra bytes per color. For example, this puts 5 colors `#616263`, `#646566`, ..., `#6d6e6f` (as 15 numbers between 0 and 1) on the stack:

`(abcdefghijklmno){255 div}forall`

In general you might have to use unprintable characters in the string.